# SQL Select to limit results to X of each id value in a specific column

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to select up to lets say 2 results per key that I have in my table.

My table looks like the following

```
uid map
1   11
1   12
1   16
1   21
1   26
2   1
2   11
2   14
2   12
2   22
3   12
3   15
3   16
```

What Im looking to do is select up to 2 rows of data for each uid

example results:

```
uid map
1   11
1   12
2   1
2   11
3   12
3   15
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: This is known as the "greatest N per group" problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ANSI-standard SQL, the simplest way is `row_number()`:

```
select uid, map
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by uid order by map) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know what I would need to do to make sure that Column 1 paired with column 2 are unique?

Comment: @user1857654 . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM   table1 a
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    table1 b
            WHERE a.uid = b.uid AND 
                  a.map <= b.map
        ) <= 2